# Is there a list of research funding agencies worldwide, ordered by money spent?

Tags: funding, international, reference-request

I have found a [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_research_and_development_spending) ranking countries based on amount of funding and GDP.  Is there a list that breaks this down further by funding agencies?

For example, the wiki list says US funding, but I imagine it's not so simple or clear where it comes from.  For example, it's not clear how much comes from NSF, NIH, and DARPA.

How can I find out the largest funding agnecies in the world?

Comment: any reason for the random up and down votes?

Answer (score 1):

I have not found a worlwide list, but I would suggest you to ask for a Demo in these websites:

- [Research Professional](http://info.researchprofessional.com/)
- [Pivot](http://pivot.cos.com/)

I found the links [here](http://sciencecareers.sciencemag.org/funding).

Answer (score 1):

The numbers in the wikipedia table you link to are suspect in my mind. The [source article](http://www.battelle.org/media/news/2011/12/16/battelle-r-d-magazine-annual-global-funding-forecast-predicts-r-d-spending-growth-will-continue-while-globalization-accelerates) doesn't provide the data that the wiki article suggest. If we believe the data that are in that article, private industry in the US spends $280 billion on R&D while the government spends $126 billion. While the private industry funding is staggeringly large, it probably means that no individual company is spending huge amounts and therefore can probably be left out of your ranking.

Of the $126 billion that the US spends, the [DOD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Military_budget_of_the_United_States) and [NIH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Institutes_of_Health) spend $64 billion and $26 billion respectively on research which is 70% of the pot. Additionally, [NASA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Budget_of_NASA), [NSF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Science_Foundation), [FDA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Food_and_Drug_Administration), and [DARPA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DARPA) have budgets of $18, $7, $4, and $2.8 billion, respectively. While that is not all R&D, it probably covers the big players.

As for other countries, the [RCUK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Research_Councils_UK), which is the major funder in the UK has a total budget of £3 billion which is spread over the 7 sub councils. In Germany, the [DFG](http://www.research-in-germany.de/en/research-funding/funding-organisations/german-research-foundation-dfg.html) and [MPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max_Planck_Society) have budgets of €2.7 and €1.5 billion.

If we ignore Japan and China (and I have no idea who funds research in those countries), the list looks like

- US DOD: $64 billion
- US NIH: $26 billion
- US NASA: $18 billion (maybe if they actually do R&D)
- US NFS: $7 billion
- everybody else:

Comment: To me the Wikipedia table seems a dubious comparison tool as it crunches together data from all kinds of sources. The more comparable sources seem to be the [OECD](http://www.oecd.org/innovation/inno/researchanddevelopmentstatisticsrds.htm) and the [UNESCO](http://www.unesco.org/new/en/natural-sciences/science-technology/prospective-studies/unesco-science-report/unesco-science-report-2010/) which are also sometimes used in the Wikipedia table.

Answer (score 1):

StrongBad has already correctly identified the biggest funding agencies in the US. Nonetheless, here are some more European:

- European Union: [Framework Programmes for Research and Technological Development 7](http://ec.europa.eu/research/fp7/index_en.cfm?pg=budget) €11 billion, from which [European Research Council](http://erc.europa.eu/about-erc/facts-and-figures) approx. €1.7 billion
- Belgium: [Fonds de la Recherche Scientifique](http://www.fnrs.be/index.php/le-fonds/notre-organisation/les-finances-du-fnrs) €0.18 billion, [Fonds voor Wetenschappelijk Onderzoek](http://www.geschiedenisfwo.be/graphic/financiele-statistieken/23) €0.18
- France: [Centre National de la Recherche Scientifique](http://www.cnrs.fr/en/aboutCNRS/key-figures.htm) €3.3 billion
- Germany: [Helmholtz Association](http://www.helmholtz.de/en/about_us/facts_and_figures/) €3.99 billion, [Fraunhofer](http://www.fraunhofer.de/en/about-fraunhofer/facts-and-figures/finances/total-business-volume-2009-2013.html) approx. €2 billion, [Leibniz Association](http://www.leibniz-gemeinschaft.de/en/about-us/leibniz-in-figures/) €1.53 billion
- Netherlands: [Nederlandse Organisatie voor Wetenschappelijk Onderzoek](http://www.nwo.nl/en/about-nwo/what+does+nwo+do/funding/budget) €0.6 billion
- Spain: [Consejo Superior de Investigaciones Científicas](http://www.csic.es/datos-sobre-el-csic) €0.68 billion
- Switzerland: [Swiss National Science Foundation](http://www.snf.ch/en/theSNSF/profile/facts_figures/statistics/Pages/default.aspx)  CHF 0.8 billion